# Test very simple async function on jasmine

Tags: angularjs, jasmine, karma-jasmine, angular-promise

I need to test this function,

I see various post but i can make it works

I tried with 'done' callback too

I tried putting the $apply call outside the it too

**testfile**

```
describe('description', function() {
  var asi;
  var root;
  var res;

  beforeEach(module('moduloPrueba'));
  beforeEach(inject(function (asincronico, $rootScope) {
           asi = asincronico;
           root = $rootScope;
       })
  );


  it('uno', function(){

      asi.tes().then(function(po){
          res = po;    
      });

      root.$digest();
      expect(res).toBe(9);
  });

});
```

**service**

```
angular.module('moduloPrueba', [])
  .factory('asincronico', function($q) {

  return {
    tes:tes,
  };

  function tes(){

    var deferred = $q.defer();

    setTimeout(function () {
      deferred.resolve(9);
    }, 500);

    return deferred.promise;
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you should use `$timeout` angularjs service instead of setTimeout.

You can test your code like below using `$timeout.flush();`:

```
it('uno', function(){

  asi.tes().then(function(po){
      res = po;    
  });
  $timeout.flush();
  $timeout.verifyNoPendingTasks();
  root.$digest();
  expect(res).toBe(9);
```

});

Here is the working example: [$timeout async test in angularjs](https://plnkr.co/edit/SEkL1M?p=preview)

Answer (score 1):

at this point you're not waiting for the promise:

```
  it('uno', function(){

      asi.tes().then(function(po){
          res = po;    
      });

      root.$digest();
      expect(res).toBe(9);
  });
```

root.$digest(); and expect(res).toBe(9); are called immediately after asi.tes().
You can mark your function as async and wait for the promise with await:

```
 it('uno', async function(){

      res = await asi.tes();

      root.$digest();
      expect(res).toBe(9);
  });
```

Comment: PLEASE HELP ME. it throws me Timeout - Async callback was not invoked within timeout specified by jasmine.DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_INTERVAL . 
describe('description', function() {
  var asi;
  var root;
  var res;

  beforeEach(module('moduloPrueba'));
  beforeEach(inject(function (asincronico, $rootScope) {
      asi = asincronico;
      root = $rootScope;
    })
  );


  it('uno', async function(){

    res = await asi.tes();

    root.$digest();
    expect(res).toBe(9);
  });

});

Comment: https://jasmine.github.io/2.4/introduction.html#section-Asynchronous_Support , you need a done callback